# Reputation increased by 1 point

Tags: support, reputation

I recently just saw a jump in my reputation by one point. How does this happen? 
Is this a bug in the system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps an answer that you had downvoted was recently deleted.